# Execute start-dfs.sh fail to start hdfs daemons

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am very confused about Hadoop configuration about core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml. I feel that start-dfs.sh script not actually use the setting. I use hdfs user to format the Namenode successfully but execute start-dfs.sh can not start hdfs daemons. Can anyone help me! here is the error message:

```
[hdfs@I26C ~]$ start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [I26C]
I26C: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/hdfs’: Permission denied
I26C: chown: cannot access ‘/hdfs/hdfs’: No such file or directory
I26C: starting namenode, logging to /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-I26C.out
I26C: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
I26C: head: cannot open ‘/hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-I26C.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
I26C: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
I26C: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.15: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/hdfs’: Permission denied
10.1.226.15: chown: cannot access ‘/hdfs/hdfs’: No such file or directory
10.1.226.15: starting datanode, logging to /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26C.out
10.1.226.15: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.16: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs’: Permission denied
10.1.226.16: chown: cannot access ‘/edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs’: No such file or directory
10.1.226.16: starting datanode, logging to /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26D.out
10.1.226.16: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26D.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.15: head: cannot open ‘/hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26C.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
10.1.226.15: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.15: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.16: head: cannot open ‘/edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26D.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
10.1.226.16: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26D.out: No such file or directory
10.1.226.16: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-I26D.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/hdfs’: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/hdfs/hdfs’: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-I26C.out
0.0.0.0: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-I26C.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /edw/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /hdfs/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode-I26C.out: No such file or directory
```

Here is the info about my deployment

master:

```
 hostname: I26C
 IP:10.1.226.15
```

Slave:

```
 hostname:I26D
 IP:10.1.226.16
```

Hadoop version: 2.7.2

OS: CentOS 7

JAVA: 1.8

I have create four users:

```
groupadd hadoop
useradd -g hadoop hadoop
useradd -g hadoop hdfs
useradd -g hadoop mapred
useradd -g hadoop yarn
```

The HDFS namenode and datanode dir privileges :

```
drwxrwxr-x. 3 hadoop hadoop 4.0K Apr 26 15:40 hadoop-data
```

The core-site.xml setting:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/edw/hadoop-data/</value>
    <description>Temporary Directory.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.1.226.15:54310</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

The hdfs-site.xml setting:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///edw/hadoop-data/dfs/namenode</value>
    <description>Determines where on the local filesystem the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage). If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///edw/hadoop-data/dfs/datanode</value>
    <description>Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored.
    </description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You may verify which configs are getting loaded , echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR. Also verify those directories are created beforehand and have proper write permission by hdfs user.

Answer (score 0):

The hdfs user doesn't have permission for the hadoop folders.
Lets say, you are using hdfs user and hadoop group to run the hadoop setup. Then you need to run following command :

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop <directory-name>
```

Give the appropriate Read-write-execute permission to your logged in user.

Comment: Even though I change the owner to _hdfs_ and setting executable privilege, but it still fail, I curious why it need create a directory in` /hdfs` ?  It need root privilege in / create directory, but the namenode and datanode directory is in `/edw/hadoop-data/dfs/`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the problem, thank you guys.

The hadoop log configuration **HADOOP_LOG_DIR** setting in `/etc/profile` can not be used in hadoop-env.sh. So the HADOOP_LOG_DIR default is empty, the start-dfs.sh use the default directory setting by hadoop-env.sh

```
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER
```

I use hdfs use to preform the start-dfs.sh the HADOOP_LOG_DIR set to /hdfs, so it will not have privilege to create directory.

Here is my new solution edit ${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh set **HADOOP_LOG_DIR**:

```
HADOOP_LOG_DIR="/var/log/hadoop"
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER
```